# Is there a way to prevent to expand type? (in TypeScript)

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to prevent to expand type? (in TypeScript)

It is very difficult to check the type in VS Code because the complex type (`Convert` in the following example) is expanded.
Is there any way to get a simple proxy type for the following use case?

```
const Neko = {
  cry: 'nyan',
} as const;

const Cat = {
  type: 'array',
  cry: 'meow',
} as const;

const Dog = {
  type: 'object',
  cry: 'bow',
} as const;

// (used by other modules)
export const refs = {
  Neko, Cat, Dog,
};

type Convert<T extends Record<string, any>> = 
  T['type'] extends 'array' ? [T['cry']] : T['type'] extends 'object' ? { cry: T['cry'] } : T['cry'];

// The type "RefOf" to get Convert<(typeof refs)[T]> by input the name of one of property of refs
type RefOf<T extends keyof typeof refs> = Convert<(typeof refs)[T]>;

declare function cat(): RefOf<'Cat'>;


const a = cat(); // I want "RefOf<"Cat">"
```

Comment: As of the latest verstion (5.2.2) your code does show `RefOf<'Cat'>`.

Answer (score -1):

Type alias names are not guaranteed to be preserved.

Check out the TS Handbook- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#differences-between-type-aliases-and-interfaces.

Here's a playground demoing the different behaviors of type aliases and interfaces: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEGEHsFsAcEsA2BTATqNrLusgzngIYDm+oA7koqIYuYQJ56gCueyoAUCKAC4AWHAHaFcoSADMaQ0PCG80EwgGNkALk6c5C1EtWgAsqOi1QAb06groEbjWg8vVHOKcAvpokshy3vEgyyMr8kEbQJogAFND2YREAlOaW1soBeJAoAHSIkMTRmbbI8e6aPMiZxJmgACqCGKhY6ABGyDnkFFQ0dIzMbBwCwqIccabcYLyQoKjIEmh8kwN8DLAc5PzwwbLMyAAeK77IACYaQSEjUWZWhfYAjABMAMwALA+gbsVjoADqgjKESytQPxCHghAByXigYgBfr8LAsYj8aQMUASbDQcRSExCeCwFiIQh+AKfAYyBiQFgOPyIaikSGLQo0Zj-aazaY+dSaXjLDgAGXgAC9CKhDqAALxJaw2Ib2RzOISuDycLw+ImBYKQflCkWRRD2LXCw6JCxS1JCdJZHJ5RAFIbFJU8ADKC3WzEcnVZaGYE1ABpFnFOmsFhsil2uoHuzwArO9SmAAEIsSFrZB-GgAjjA5gtVN8VCEc1o1C4Q4AGlR2AwO1EsBQoAAbvB-gJ4HhPgB5aDwem-Ph1TCV3AEEirTp4ELtRbTPD4vwKjOfAuioSQHuDXBcnmgACC+eCONFEs73YAPGGZVT5cRyyhiHh7AAON7lsG3vBggB8XGV3l8-nVISOgghxoLq9i7io-AHsayRWGaFrlFauq2rg9qaIGQHwCBqChtKdgRo8TxRjeyB3o+7xAA)